# Instant log out in Samba and winbind

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm trying to log in to my domain with ubuntu, i already configured samba and winbind, the login seems successful, but when it logs in, instantly it logs out...

[image]

And then it just show this and logs out...

[image]

Comment: This question would be better suited for [su] or [sf] because it doesn't involve programming as such.

Comment: When i log in with a local user it logs in, with no errors, so it's a samba error or winbin...